# BizTalk XML default transmit pipeline failing when processing

Tags: c#, biztalk

I have built an orchestration to demonstrate using the default XMLPipeline in Visual Studio and deployed it to BizTalk 2020. I restarted the HostInstances and made sure the dll is in the GAC. The schema is deployed in the schemas folder. When I run it this error comes up: (partial error shown)
"URI: "C:\BizTalkRuntime\REC_FOLDER_XML*.xml" Reason: Finding the document specification by message type "InputToProcess" failed. Verify the schema deployed properly."

Start of XMLFile FileName MMD.xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <InputToProcess> <Item>`

Start of XMLSchema FileName MMD.xsd

````
    ```<?xml version="1.0"?>
      <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://UsingXMLPipeline.MMD" 
        xmlns="http://UsingXMLPipeline.MMD" 
          xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" 
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:element name="InputToProcess">
           <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
                       <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>```
````

Every thing looks correct?
Anyone have any ideas.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have a namespace in the schema, but not in the Xml instance.

Either add the namespace to the Xml or remove the namespace from the schema, whatever suits you best.

Added NS to the Xml
InputToProcess xmlns="http://UsingXMLPipeline.MMD"

(Could write tags since I'm on a mobile)

Comment: Ok, I removed the namespace from the schema, along with the target namespace. It looks like it's going forward, getting subscription error now, which i can take from here. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Ok, works! Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome :)